# Google Chrome F12 console not showing warnings?

Tags: google-chrome, console

I'm using Google Chrome 30 (stable, not beta or canary; Windows 8) and for some reason it's displaying that I have five warnings but it's not showing what those warnings are in the console.

[image]

I can access the cause of the warnings by finding the faulty file in the sidebar (under Frames > *.html) but I was wondering if there was something I could do to make it display the warnings in the actual log. I have tried clicking on the (!5) icon, clicking "Warnings" instead of "All" and selecting the actual file but none of these seem to display the warnings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your logging filter (eg http://puu.sh/4XrSx.png) to see errors that are being hidden from console.

Another note is you can make chrome pause a script on an exception in the scripts tabs (eg http://puu.sh/4XrLR.png) by setting the pause on exceptions setting

Comment: Ah, I didn't have "CSS" checked in the "filters" pin tab. That solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

by ctrl+shift+j => setting => General => cancel the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"